# Adding Custom Object to Linked List, The List is getting corrupted

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have the following code.

```
private static Prints someprint = new Prints();
private static LinkedList<Prints> LList = new LinkedList<Prints>(); 


public static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();
    someprint.ChangePrint(101.18, 101.16, 16, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:20"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 6:50:10 PM"));                
    LList.AddLast(someprint);
    
    someprint.ChangePrint(101.20, 101.10, 200, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:20"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 6:50:10 PM"));
    LList.AddLast(someprint);                
    
    someprint.ChangePrint(102.38, 102.36, 16, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:40"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 7:15:15 PM"));
    LList.AddLast(someprint);
    
    LinkedListNode<Prints> somenode = new LinkedListNode<Prints>(new Prints());

    somenode = LList.First;
    
    Console.WriteLine("LList");
    while (somenode != null)
    {
        somenode.Value.PrintToScreen();
        somenode = somenode.Next;
    }
    
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is the Ouput i am getting.

```
LList
Sell Print
Start of Print=102.38
End of Print=102.36
Volume in Print=16
Time Spanned by Print=00:00:40
Time Stamp = 4/8/2014 7:15:15 PM
Sell Print
Start of Print=102.38
End of Print=102.36
Volume in Print=16
Time Spanned by Print=00:00:40
Time Stamp = 4/8/2014 7:15:15 PM
Sell Print
Start of Print=102.38
End of Print=102.36
Volume in Print=16
Time Spanned by Print=00:00:40
Time Stamp = 4/8/2014 7:15:15 PM
```

I can't seem to figure out why all the 3 prints in the LinkedList are the same.

I tried a sample program with just integer values and it worked.

I tried printing `List.Last.Value.PrintToScreen();` just after the values are added and at that point, it prints the right values. But i can't seem to be able to retrieve the linked list.
Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Now you add same instance of Prints to the list 3 times. You need to create separate instances.

```
private static LinkedList<Prints> LList = new LinkedList<Prints>();

public static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Prints someprint = new Prints();
    someprint.ChangePrint(101.18, 101.16, 16, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:20"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 6:50:10 PM"));
    LList.AddLast(someprint);

    someprint = new Prints();
    someprint.ChangePrint(101.20, 101.10, 200, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:20"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 6:50:10 PM"));
    LList.AddLast(someprint);

    someprint = new Prints();
    someprint.ChangePrint(102.38, 102.36, 16, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:40"), DateTime.Parse("4/8/2014 7:15:15 PM"));
    LList.AddLast(someprint);

    LinkedListNode<Prints> somenode = new LinkedListNode<Prints>(new Prints());

    somenode = LList.First;

    Console.WriteLine("LList");
    while (somenode != null)
    {
        somenode.Value.PrintToScreen();
        somenode = somenode.Next;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: And in this case, I would actually pass the whole set of data into the constructor, rather than creating an empty object without meaning, and then calling `ChangePrint` on it directly afterwards.

Comment: But the value is different each time. When i use LList.Last.Value.PrintToScreen after each addition to LList, it is printing the right values

Comment: @CompuChip Yes, it makes sense. I just wanted to point to the problem with minimum code modification.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I agree, that's why I'm pointing it out in a comment, so novice can do with it as he pleases.

Comment: ok I modified the code and what you said works. May i know why i cant do what i did, since the value is different each time. The same thing i do with an integer in a LinkedList works.

Comment: @novice Integer is value-type and it's copied. In your case there is one object changed with each `ChangePrint` call. It is same to the case of 3 persons having information about the location of **single** box at storage room and each of them changes the content of the box (object). In the end they get the content of that **single** box, which, of course, will be same for them. So you need to create separate box for each person.

Comment: oh ok. i get it now. last someprint changes the content of all three nodes. why is it still associated with Llist object though? i thought AddLast would just copy an object having the same value as someprint to the LinkedList

Comment: @novice Yes, you get it right. AddLast doesn't copy an object, it copies the address (location of the box).

Comment: But if it copied the address why is the working with an integer different?

Comment: thanks a lot btw! took me a long time on this one :)

Comment: @novice In case of integer it is a value-type, so the content is copied, not the address. [Value Types (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Comment: oh ok Thanks. Can i do someting to destroy somenode = new Prints(); which i have added after each line. This was just a sample code to figure out the error on a larger code. it may cause some overhead to create a new somenode each time without destroying the previous object, or is it done automatically when i put somenode= new Prints(), the reference would get changed but is the object destroyed, will it cause any overhead

Comment: @novice You shouldn't destroy it, since it is referenced by your list. CLR will take care of the things.

Comment: ah right. that seems logical. I get it now. Thanks for your help